# How to short-circuit reduce on Stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Suppose I have a stream of boolean values and the reduce operation that I am writing is `||` (OR). Can I write it in a way such that the evaluation of at least some of the elements is abandoned if a `true` value is encountered?

I am looking for some amount of optimization (perhaps if it is a parallel stream), not necessarily full optimization although the latter would be awesome.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I suspect you want this type of construct.

```
// stop when any element evaluates to true
boolean any = stream.anyMatch(t -> t);
```

You can check this with peek

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4).peek(System.out::println).anyMatch(i -> i == 2);
```

prints

```
1
2
```

For a parallel example

```
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
IntStream.range(0, 1000).parallel().peek(t -> count.incrementAndGet()).anyMatch(i -> i == 2);
System.out.println("count: " + count);
```

prints a number like

```
count: 223
```

The exact number varies.

For a referencePipeline, the `anyMatch` calls

```
@Override
public final boolean anyMatch(Predicate<? super P_OUT> predicate) {
    return evaluate(MatchOps.makeRef(predicate, MatchOps.MatchKind.ANY));
}
```

which calls this

```
public static <T> TerminalOp<T, Boolean> makeRef(Predicate<? super T> predicate,
        MatchKind matchKind) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(predicate);
    Objects.requireNonNull(matchKind);
    class MatchSink extends BooleanTerminalSink<T> {
        MatchSink() {
            super(matchKind);
        }

        @Override
        public void accept(T t) {
            if (!stop && predicate.test(t) == matchKind.stopOnPredicateMatches) {
                stop = true;
                value = matchKind.shortCircuitResult;
            }
        }
    }

    return new MatchOp<>(StreamShape.REFERENCE, matchKind, MatchSink::new);
}
```

where you can start to see the short circuiting code.

Comment: +1 thanks. I am looking for how to implement constructs such as `anyMatch` (can't find the source code somehow in my Eclipse).

Comment: @necromancer The source is there, but it's not easy to read, it's pretty convoluted.  Even the simple `.count()` is way more complicated than you might imagine. I suggest trying to use the constructs already available to do what you want.

Comment: Ahem, you can’t rely on `peek` for a parallel stream. At the time, `anyMatch` recognizes that there is a match, `peek` might have seen a lot of matches already.

Comment: @Holger I agree, which is why I got `223` on one run and "The exact number varies"  I was relying on the fact that peek might show the stream was short circuited.

Comment: why not use `findFirst` to ensure elements are visited in sequence?